# JavaScript result happening before callbacks complete

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm totally new to JS having jumped in a few days ago to try make a chrome extension, so sorry if this is a simple problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

My original function was to simply download an image and increment the stored count by 1 and add on the file size. However on a page of images it hit the write limits of chrome so I decided to count the values and write them at the end.

Initially the return value happened much later than when the function was executed (so it returned nothing), so I looked up how to fix it and got it working with a callback. However, although it waits for the callbacks, the code just continues past the callbacks and the part afterwards is executed before anything else, meaning the final count will always be 0.

```
    // Loop through all urls
    var approx_filesize = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < all_urls.length; i++){
        var image_url = all_urls[i];
        _download_image(image_url, folder_name, function(item){
            approx_filesize += parseInt(item);
        });
    }

    // This happens before any _download_image functions complete
    alert('end' + approx_filesize);

    // Write to storage
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        download_count: 0,
        download_size: 0
    }, function(items) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            download_count: parseInt(items.download_count) + all_images_data.length - 1,
            download_size: parseInt(items.download_size) + approx_filesize
        }, function() {
        });
    });
```

I just tried moving the loop into its own callback function and still had no luck, the alert runs before the first function completes.

```
function image_url_loop_callback(callback, folder_name, all_urls){

    var approx_filesize = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < all_urls.length; i++){
        var image_url = all_urls[i];

        _download_image(image_url, folder_name, function(filesize){
            approx_filesize += parseInt(filesize);
        });
    }
    callback(approx_filesize);
}

image_url_loop_callback(function(approx_filesize){
    alert(approx_filesize);
}, folder_name, all_urls);
```

How do I make it so that the loop completes before anything else is done?

Edit: Got it working with promise, here's the adjusted code:

```
new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    var count = 1;
    var num_items = all_urls.length;
    var approx_filesize = 0;
    for(var i = 1; i < num_items; i++){
        var image_url = all_urls[i];

        _download_image(image_url, folder_name, function(item){
            approx_filesize += parseInt(item);
            count ++;
            if(count == num_items){
                resolve([num_items, approx_filesize]);
            }
        });
    }
}).then( function(stuff) {
    var num_items = stuff[0];
    var approx_filesize = stuff[1];
    chrome.storage.sync.get({
        download_count: 0,
        download_size: 0
    }, function(items) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({
            download_count: parseInt(items.download_count) + num_items,
            download_size: parseInt(items.download_size) + approx_filesize
        }, function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you have to handle the asynchronous aspect of JavaScript.

To do so, you have to use a Promise.

This works this way:

```
new Promise( () => {

    // My asynchronous code

}).then( () => {

    // My code which need to wait for the promise resolution.

});
```

If you are working with only the latest versions of browsers, you can also have a look at async/await keywords which make asynchronous handling much easier than regular promises (but still are promises).

EDIT: As this answer required further explanation and proper code snippets, I edited it to answer a comment.

This example maybe easier to understand:

```
let myFoo = "Hello";

test = new Promise( (resolve) => {

    console.log(myFoo);

    myFoo = "World!";

    setTimeout(() => {

        resolve();

    }, 4000);

}).then( () => {

    console.log(myFoo);

});
```

This will print "Hello" immediately, and "World!" 4 seconds after.

This is how you work with promises. You can perfectly edit variables which are defined in a scope outside of the promise. Please don't use var, just stick to let and define a decent scope.

Comment: Thanks, was just about to clarify with the other guy how to do use it, just trying it out now :)

Comment: Slight problem - I need a variable from the `promise` to go into the `then` part, and it appears you use `resolve`, but that's then executing before the rest completes haha. How do I get the variable over?

Comment: I edited my answer to give you a proper example since I'm not sure what was the problem you encountered.

Comment: Thanks, it was running the loop and executing resolve too fast, though I managed to fix it by just incrementing a count of each time the function completed. Hopefully this way, even if it takes a long time, it should still work :)

Answer (score 2):

Due to javascript's async nature you have to use promises:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises